# SDK connection with Mavic 2 Enterprise

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm building software to control a Mavic 2 enterprise through Android SDK in order to make the drone autonomous for a project but We would not like to use a cellphone to do it.
Is there any possibility to control this specific drone without using the remote controller?
Tks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Onboard SDK with an onboard computer.

https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/development-workflow/hardware-setup.html

The Android SDK may not provide autonomous control outside the range of the android phone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).